# mounting EFS on MacBook Pro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

There's a number of <2017 recipes on the internet on how to mount an EFS locally on a MacBook Pro, for instance, using reverse HAProxy
 like [here](https://xan-manning.co.uk/2016/09/08/mounting-efs-outside-of-aws.html) or using SSHFS. Can anyone suggest which scenario works well now (late 2018)?

Answer (score 4):

When you mentioned old posts using HAProxy to mount EFS outside AWS, I thought you might referring to [Serverfault: Elastic file system (EFS) mount outside of AWS](https://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161).  That is still, essentially, the only way to do it.

EFS filesystems are designed only to be used within a single VPC or across AWS Direct Connect.  Any other application still requires a proxy, and is officially "unsupported" (but works as expected).